# How can I run my .liquid file without on a shopify website

Tags: shopify, liquid

How can I start to run my .liquid files and codes?

Eg, if using react we can run 'npm start' and use localhost

But for shopify is that we necessary need a shopify website for it?

I am playing around with their template 'timber' but how can I run and see that is my code working? Or there is another similar to 'npm start' stuff for liquid?

Comment: You can't run a shopify site fully locally - however you can get close with Themekit (https://shopify.github.io/themekit/) - it can watch for changes to your liquid files and upload them to your shopify store so you can preview them there.

Comment: Can I watch it without a store then? Or it is a must for me to have a store in order to see my changes ? Because I am just trying out the changes only